# Noob Concern: T-SQL sub-queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table `bbc` with the following columns:

- `name` (refers to a name of a country within a particular region of the world)
- `region` (continent of the world)
- `population` (population of the country in the name name field)

The question I'm trying to answer:

*Find each country that belongs to a region where all populations are less than 250000000.  Show name, region and population.*

I was thinking the answer might be something like:

```
SELECT name, region, population 
FROM bbc 
GROUP by region 
HAVING MAX(population) < 250000000
```

I get the feeling I am way off course with this answer... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.name, b.region, b.population
from bbc as b
where
    b.region in
    (
        select t.region
        from bbc as t
        group by t.region
        having max(t.population) < 25000000
    )
```

Comment: You know what's interesting... I see your answer and it seems completely correct to me.  But when I used it as the answer instead of what I posted, it provides a very different returned result of data.  Please look at:  sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Comment: When I enter your query... which to me seems identical to mine but you are using aliases, I get a different result back.  What do you make of this???  O_o

Comment: :) try it now. You have wrong number in your question - **250 000 000** instead of **25 000 000**

Comment: also I'm always using aliases, because sometimes you can get very nasty errors without it, and I don't mean compilation errors

Answer (score 2):

It was complaining about how name and population did not exist in my GROUP BY.  So I used a sub-query as a work around this problem.

```
SELECT name, region, population FROM bbc
WHERE region IN

(SELECT region FROM bbc 
GROUP BY region 
HAVING MAX(population) < 25000000)
```

Comment: you need `IN` rather than `=` as there might be more than one.

Comment: Almost - you need an `IN()` clause rather than `=` because it may return multiple rows.

Comment: It will work with only top 1 region, take a look at my answer, there's `in` :)

Comment: @MonuMan5 It is syntactically correct _if_ the subquery returns only one region.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  b.name, 
  b.region, 
  b.population
From
  bbc b
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select
      'x'
    From
      bbc b2
    Where
      b.region = b2.region And
      b.population > 250000000
  )
```